# Reading a configfs file

Tags: file, linux-kernel, config

I am writing an user space process that will read data from the configfs entry continuously. I have defined callback function for read in kernel.
When I invoke read in a loop, only for the first time callback is called and for the next iterations control is not hitting the callback.

Kernel callback for read is simple function that will return a character.

```
static ssize_t show(struct config_item *item, char *page)
{
    static char a = 'a';
    printk("reading data\n");
    page[0] = a++; 
    return 1;
}
```

User space process will read the data and display it on the screen.

```
int main()
{
   int fd = open("/sys/kernel/config/sample/showme", O_RDONLY);
   int ret;
   int i = 5;
   char receive[8];

   if (fd < 0) {
       perror("Failed to open the device...");
       return errno;
   }
   while(i--) {
       ret = read(fd, receive, 1);
       if (ret < 0) {
           perror("Failed to read the message\n");
           return errno;
       }
       printf("Message is %x with size %d\n", receive[0], ret);
   }
   close(fd);
}
```

output:
    Message is 61 with size 1
    Message is 61 with size 0
    Message is 61 with size 0
    Message is 61 with size 0
    Message is 61 with size 0

Note: The flow goes well if I close and open the file for all reads.

How to fix the above problem? I want the data to be reflected on all read.

Answer (score 2):

A file under *configfs* filesystem is interpreted as an *attribute*, which have *specific* finite content at any moment.

E.g., a file may have content:

- "123" at moment 1ns
- "abc" at moment 2ns
- "" (empty) at moment 3ns

and so on.

Moreover, configfs filesystem ensures, that after opening the file, any `read()` performed by the user will see portion of data **consistent** with other `read()`s. Assuming the example above, user won't read first symbol "1" (as at moment 1ns), 2nd symbol "b" (as at moment 2ns) and then found 3d symbol to be absent (as at moment 3ns).

So, after opening the file, `.show()` method is **called once**, and is expected to return **whole content** of the file. This content (or an appropriate portion of it) is returned upon futher `read` requests from the user.

Consistency guarantee is cleared at closing the file; so when you open it again, `.show()` will be called once more, and user's `read` requests will return updated content of the file.

> I am writing an user space process that will read data from the configfs entry continuously.

With this semantic abstraction of finite file's content is lost, so you cannot implement that for configfs files.

However, you may implement this semantic with any "general" filesystem, which allows directly to set `file_operations` callbacks. You may create a file, e.g., under *debugfs* (`/sys/kernel/debug/`):

```
ssize_t my_read (struct file * filp, char __user * buf, size_t size, loff_t * offp)
{
    static char a = 'a';
    printk("reading data\n");
    a++;
    copy_to_user(buf, &a, 1);
    return 1;
}

struct file_operations my_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = &my_read
};

int module_init(void)
{
    debugfs_create_file("showme", S_IRUGO, NULL, NULL, &my_ops);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and I wanted to avoid performance penalty caused by closing and opening the file on each read.

I found out that the `show()` callback of the kernel driver is executed on each read if it was preceded by a write operation by the same process.

Of course I wanted the `show()` callback in particular to be executed if the configfs attribute had been written by another process. And of course I did not want to overwrite the attribute before reading.

What I finally did was to execute a `pwrite()` of zero length before reading:

```
static bool sample_read(int fd)
{
    char buf[2] = { 0 };
    ssize_t sz, buf_sz = sizeof(buf);
    char *endptr = NULL;
    int ret;

    /**
     * This 0 length write ensures that the configfs is updated, i.e. its
     * `show()` callback in kernel space is called on next read.
     * Alternatively the fd could be closed and a opened anew.
     */
    sz = pwrite(fd, buf, 0, 0);

    if (sz != 0) {
        perror("Failed to write\n");
        return false;
    }

    sz = pread(fd, buf, buf_sz, 0);

    if (sz != buf_sz) {
        perror("Failed to read\n");
        return false;
    }

    ret = strtoul(buf, &endptr, 0);

    if (ret < 0 || endptr != buf + 1) {
        perror("Failed to parse\n");
        return false;
    }

    /* convert integer to bool */
    return !!ret;
}
```

I did some performance tests.

This is the result for the solution above (~23k reads):

```
cpu time 0.000000s
cpu Utime 0.010000s
cpu Stime 0.060000s
cpu CStime 0.000000s
```

And this is the result for the same test if I close and open the file descriptor:

```
cpu time 0.000000s
cpu Utime 0.040000s
cpu Stime 0.810000s
cpu CStime 0.000000s
```